# Does Apache Cassandra 3.11.4 support more than 1TB storage per node?

Tags: cassandra

if i use 1 TB storage per node it will need 120 Nodes Cassandra cluster . this is increasing infrastructure cost business side.
we are planing to increase storage 4TB per node to reduce Cassandra nodes. so that i can use 30 nodes .

Question:
**please confirm, Does Apache Cassandra 3.11.4 support more than 1TB storage per node using normal HDD not using SSD disks without impact of the performance?

cassandra version : 3.11.4
OS version: CentOs 7.3
RAM: 32 GB
CPU: 8 core cpu
Compaction Strategy: Size tiered
Consistency: Local_Quorum
Heap: XMs:8GB Xmx:16GB

Comment: it's too broad question, and nobody will able to guarantee that it will work until you narrow it down to specific requirements, etc.

Comment: @AlexOtt: Datastax has recommendations around how much max disk size you can attach to a single node. Example: For DataStax Enterprise version 6.0 and earlier: 1TB per node For DataStax Enterprise version 6.7 and later: 2TB per node. The question is trying to seek if there are known limits or disk size more than 1TB/2TB can be used with apache cassandra


confusion is more than 2GB also possible or not.

Comment: it's all depends on the use cases, and specific requirements - it's not the limit of the disk, etc., but it's more that if you have too much data you may not able to meet your SLAs. Recommendation from DataStax is a general recommendation, that may vary depending on use case and requirements